# Using TestRestTemplate to test a OncePerRequestFilter in integration test

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-rest, spring-boot-test

My OncePerRequestFilter class structure is as follows :

```
@Component
Class FilterA extends OncePerRequestFilter{

@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res, FilterChain chain){

Obj A = externalService1();
Obj B = externalService2();

req.setAttribute("attr1", A);
req.setAttribute("attr2", B);

chain.doFilter(req,res);

}

}
```

I want to write an integration test that will spin up the application context and allow me to submit a http request again the running server. For this purpose I used TestRestTemplate like below

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class TestA {

@Test
public void testResponse(){

MultiValueMap<String, String> headers = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
headers.add("Authorisation" : "sdsfsfsfsfsd");
ResponseEntity<String> entity = new TestRestTemplate().exchange(
"http://localhost:" + port + "/endpoint/", HttpMethod.GET , new HttpEntity<Object>(headers), String.class);

}
```

My problem is that this directly reaches the controller and skips the Filter altogether. Is there a way to force the execution of the filter class above in the TestRestTemplate?.

Comment: Which means your filter isn't regsiterd (Properly) else it would pass through the filter. Also your filter is wrong as it will break proper request handling.There should be a `chain.doFIlter(req, res)` call to not stop request processing.

Comment: Thanks.Could you please give me a hint on how i can register a filter into TestRestTemplate.

Comment: You don't. The `TestRestTemplate` just sends a request to your application, in which is apparently not installed. Is your filter an `@Component` or has an `@Bean` method to register it?

Comment: Yes its marked as a @Component. Sorry ive now corrected the code example in the question.

Comment: Make sure it is in a package that is scanned by your `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class, if it isn't it won't be detected and thus not registered.

Comment: Thank you so much. Problem was that i had a @ConditionalOnProperty on my filter to avoid swagger hits etc going via it.  What a dumb me.